# UVa 11860: How to use Heap to solve it

Tags: algorithm, heap

I am trying to solve a programming problem in UVa online judge:

[Uva 11860 Document Analyzer](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/118/11860.html)

The problem setter of this problem wrote an tutorial on `heap` and some operation on it including insertion, deletion of node and mentioned at the end of that article - this problem can be solved by using heap. There might be other ways to solve it But I can't figure out how this problem can be designed to be solved using `heap`. I know how to code a heap in C++ and can define `insert()`, `remove()`, `print()` functions and some other operations like finding minimum item etc.

How this problem is related to heap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach that comes to mind:

Have an (initially empty) heap of objects containing a word and its position - order this heap by the position.

```
smallestDistance = infinity
biggestSize = 0
for each word in the input:
   heap.insert(Pair(current position, word))
   hashMap[word] = current position

   // We saw the word after this occurrence, so remove it
   while hashMap[heap.minimum.word] != heap.minimum.position
     heap.pop()

   // We found another word!
   //   The previous smallest is invalid, since it doesn't contain this word
   if heap.size > biggestSize
     smallestDistance = currentPosition - heap.minimum
     biggestSize = heap.size
   // Is this distance better than the best so far? If so, use it instead
   else
     smallestDistance = min(smallestDistance, currentPosition - heap.minimum)
output smallestDistance
```